# Keep alive component data ? Angular and dynamic component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

All code is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keep-alive-component?file=src/app/app.component.ts

is it possible to keep the state entered and when the component changes?
I am using dynamic component - component factory resolver for rendering component but i want to keep entered values and when change component..... ?

In Vue.js for that exist keep-alive directive but is it possible and using Angular 9 ?

Example what I need:

Rendering first component ->

type in input whatever example TEST DATA ->

Change component second ->

Return on first component and see previous entered 'TEST DATA'

```
  public createComponent(component: number): void {
    const currentComponent = this.components[component];
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      currentComponent as any
    );
    let viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    let componentRef: any = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    componentRef.instance.outputEventData.subscribe((val: Object | any) => {
      if (val) {
        this.sendFilter.emit(val);
      }
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      componentRef.instance.destroyComponent.subscribe((val: any) => {
        if (val) {
          viewContainerRef.clear();
        }
      });
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: For that, I use a service. Services are always here (they're not destroyed and created all the time like components) , and since they are singletons, their data can be shared across components. From the component I use `this.myService.myVariable`, and from the template directly `{{ myService.myVariable }}`.

Comment: @JeremyThille can you help me with little code demonstration ?

Comment: Well I told you right above. In your service you have a `public myVariable:string = "test data"`. And then, from any components where this service is injected (using `constructor(public myService:MyService)`) you can access it directly : `console.log( this.myService.myVariable )` and also modify it : `this.myService.myVariable = "Other test data here"`. Display in a template : `{{ myService.myVariable }}`. The component can be destroyed and respawned, `myVariable` will stay right where it is, in the service.

Answer (score 0):

Create dataService, in data service create rxjs `Subject`, inject dataService in your two components, in first component subscribe on it, in second component after you type your input call `subject.next(typeInput)`, data will automatically get updated in your first component inside the subscription

Comment: How you think to do it ?

Comment: Why an RxJS subject? This is overkill. Any public variable in a service can be accessed directly from any component and any template. No need for Observables, subscriptions and all this stuff, just go `myService.myVariable` and bam